# Why don't Path Filters in a Pull Request Build Validation work as expected?

Tags: azure-pipelines

Or, why are path filter (as of 2019-06-14) under documented by Microsoft.

Behavior of Path Filters inside PR Build validation can be perceived as non intuitive.

Builds are started or not triggered for no obvious reason.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Confusion can arise from looking at an individual commit to trigger (or not) a build.

Key is to take into account *all* commits that comprise a PR

- previous additions/updates made in other commits should be considered
- addition and removal of the same file is considered no change.
  Let's use the term *net(to) effect* of a group of commits to draw attention to this mechanism.

Some more observations

- builds disappear from the overview if the path filter is not in scope anymore for the PR.
  So they are dynamic: existing PR (possibly in the 10's) are affected retro actively.
  This can be a good thing I suppose but also a bad+unexpected thing. Be cautious.
- Specifying a path filter (overriding the empty string in the UI) *removes* the implicit root inclusion.
  So a beginners fault is that the the following path filter is expected to only ignore changes to folder1 and pick up all other changes
  `!/folder1/*`. It doesn't. You have to explicitly add the root back in 
  `/*;!/folder1/*`

Comment: Thanks for adding the part about implicit root inclusions being removed by specifying path filters. Solved the problem I was here for :)

Comment: Yeah me too.  The intuitive behavior would be for it to not implicitly include the root if you explicitly included any paths, but still implicitly include the root if you only explicitly *excluded* paths, because that seems to be the root of the confusion if you'll forgive the pun.  Or at least, they should put it in the help text!!!

Comment: To be sure: I create a PR with changes in the path filter and the build validation gets triggered. I then push a couple of commits with some other changes NOT in the path filter. A build validation gets triggered anyway because the totality of all changes in the PR includes changes in the path filter. Correct?